# progress bar as thread during file operations wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using Wizard component in WPF. 
While click on Finish Button of wizard I doing some file operations which takes ~5 seconds.

I would like to show progress bar during file operations.

So, I did:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
     MessageWithProgressBar progress = new MessageWithProgressBar(this);
     progress.Show();
}));
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

**Some code from MessageWithProgressBar.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="title" Content="Please wait while processing.." FontSize="17.333"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ProgressBar Name="progress" IsIndeterminate="True" Value="{Binding CurrentStep, Converter={StaticResource stepToProgress}}" />
        <TextBlock Name="progressLabel" Text="{Binding ElementName=progress, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Some code from MessageWithProgressBar.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MessageWithProgressBar : Window
{
    public MessageWithProgressBar(MainWindow Mw)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = Mw;
    }
}

public class currentStepToProgressValue : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            if ((int)value <= GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep)
                return (int)Math.Floor((decimal)(8 * (int)value));
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My issue is that progress bar is immediately disappeared and I don't see the progress bar.

Any advice?

Comment: Just a quick question - why are you using a `Thread` instead of a `Task`?

Comment: @henk holterman so can you write an answer how to do that?

Comment: I don't want to use background worker since I want to update value property of progressbar via xaml by using converter and not in dowork method of background worker

Comment: But I need progressupdate event will be update from currentstep property which set and update in maineindow.xaml.cs